# How to test if a point is in a view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, position, cgpoint

I have a `UIImageView` and I have a `CGPoint` on the screen. I want to be able to test that point to see if it is in the `UIImageView`. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`CGPoint` is no good with a reference point. If your point is in window's coordinates then you can get it using

```
CGPoint locationInView = [imageView convertPoint:point fromView:imageView.window];
if ( CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.bounds, locationInView) ) {
    // Point lies inside the bounds.
}
```

You may also call [`pointInside:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622533-pointinside?language=objc) method

```
if ( [imageView pointInside:locationInView withEvent:nil] ) {
    // Point lies inside the bounds
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Tested in Swift 4

```
view.frame.contains(point)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you have a full-screen window (pretty reasonable, I think). Then you can transform the point from the window's coordinate space to the UIImageView's using:

```
CGPoint point = ...
UIWindow window = ...
UIImageView imageView = ...
CGPoint transformedPoint = [window convertPoint:point toView:imageView];
```

Then, you can test if the point is in the image view's frame as follows:

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, transformedPoint))
{
    // do something interesting....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint([myView frame], point))
```

where point is your CGPoint and myView is your UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**

```
let isPointInFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds.contains(newLocation)
```