# UIView center, frame

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, cgrect, cgpoint

I am wondering how to check if a view's center is in the frame of another UIView?
Example: if I have a circle which can be dragged by your finger and it's center point gets dragged to a square's frame some code gets executed?
Thanks in advance,
Best regards!

Comment: What research have you done? What part has you stuck and not knowing where to look? I totally understand if you're lost , I was once, but please show where you're lost.

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501073/how-to-test-if-a-point-is-in-a-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at Apple's CGGeometry Reference. In particular, you could use [CGRectContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17143).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me!
Sorry for reposting this problem, but I couldn't find the other!