# Drag a UIView on the bounds of another UIView (with a rounded corner)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Basically I have a `UIView` which I need to drag along the bounds of another `UIView` (its superview) with a rounded corner. I have already implemented a draggable `UIView`. I'm having trouble finding a way to restrict the movement of the draggable `UIView` along the edges of its superview only.

Is there a way in which I can check if the `UIView.center` is on the superview's bounds?

Anyone have any ideas on how I can implement this? Thanks

Comment: might be possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501073/how-to-test-if-a-point-is-in-a-view

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CGRectContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint) to check whether an point is inside the view frame

```
-(void) methodThatWouldBeCalledWhenTheViewISDragged {

  CGPoint smallViewCenter = smallView.center;
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(containerView.bounds, smallViewCenter) ) {
       // smallView is inside the ContainerView
    }
    else{   
       //smallView went outside
    }
  }
```

Comment: I only want the smallView to be draggable on the outside edge of the containerView. I don't want it to be able to be dragged inside.

Answer (score 0):

Use`CGRectContainsPoint()` to detect.